# How to create a row with uniformly distributed views all with same height based on the tallest view?

Tags: swiftui

I can do this easily with constraints, but struggle with SwiftUI concepts. I don't understand how/where to apply `.frame` and `fixedSize` modifiers.

I want to have two or more "boxes" (I use `Button` for this purpose) with content drawn horizontally in a row.

The boxes should be distributed uniformely and take all availble horizontal space.

The height of the boxes should be the same based on the height of the box with the tallest content.

[image]

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/

Answer (score 1):

Spreading across the available width is easy. Two ways to do this:

1. Apply `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` to each of the individual items. This grants the same space to each of the items, but if the width of an item cannot grow (perhaps because a fixed width was applied to it) then the gaps between the items will be different.
2. Put a `Spacer` between every item. This gives equal spacing.

Getting the heights to match is more tricky.

One way is to take advantage of the fact that when an `.overlay` or `.background` is applied to a `View`, these layers automatically adopt the width and height of the View they are applied to.

Here is an example that works. The idea is that the maximum height is established in the base view, then the actual presentation (with equal heights) all happens in the overlay. It does involve a certain degree of duplication, but only to the extent that the base view needs to contain the views that can actually impact the maximum height. It may be possible to save on decoration and elaborate layout in the base view, since it can be masked out if necessary by applying a background to the overlay.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var withMatchedHeight = true

    private var blueBox: some View {
        Color.blue
            .frame(width: 80)
            .overlay(Text("Blue"))
    }

    private var greenBox: some View {
        Color.green
            .frame(width: 50)
            .overlay(Text("Green"))
    }

    private var purpleBox: some View {
        Color.purple
            .frame(width: 58)
            .overlay(Text("Purple"))
    }

    private var redBox: some View {
        Color.red
            .frame(width: 45)
            .overlay(Text("Red"))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {

                // In the real world, the normal height of a box
                // should simply be determined by its content
                blueBox
                    .frame(height: 100)
                Spacer()
                greenBox
                    .frame(height: 130)
                Spacer()
                purpleBox
                    .frame(height: 75)
                Spacer()
                redBox
                    .frame(height: 105)
            }
            .overlay(
                HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    blueBox
                    Spacer()
                    greenBox
                    Spacer()
                    purpleBox
                    Spacer()
                    redBox
                }
                // All boxes should use the available height,
                // this being the height of the tallest item
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .opacity(withMatchedHeight ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            )
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)

            // The button toggles the visibility of the overlay
            Button(withMatchedHeight ? "Show normal heights" : "Show matched heights") {
                withMatchedHeight.toggle()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(Color(white: 0.9))
    }
}
```

[image: With and without alignment]