# Make UIHostingController as high as the aspectFit Image inside

Tags: swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZoomableScrollView {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .resizable()
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .scaledToFit()
          }
    }
}

struct ZoomableScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
  private var content: Content

  init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
  }

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
    // set up the UIScrollView
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator  // for viewForZooming(in:)
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = true

    // create a UIHostingController to hold our SwiftUI content
    let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
    hostedView.backgroundColor = .blue
    hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
    scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)

    return scrollView
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: self.content))
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
    // update the hosting controller's SwiftUI content
    context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = self.content
    assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
  }

  // MARK: - Coordinator

  class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>

    init(hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>) {
      self.hostingController = hostingController
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
      return hostingController.view
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to zoom in the image and scroll around.

However, after zooming in, the scroll area is unnecessarily too high.

How can I make the scroll area as high as the zoomed image (like the iOS Photos app)?

Or how can I make the UIHostingController as high as the image inside?

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out the technique I gave in an answer to [How to create a row with uniformly distributed views all with same height based on the tallest view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75880460/20386264).

The idea would be to show the image at its natural/required size in the main body of a View. Then apply an overlay showing the image (again) with the zoom functionality. The overlay is automatically constrained to the size of the main body, so this prevents the greedy space allocation from happening.

I think this adaption to your code works as you were requesting:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private var theImage: some View {
        Image(systemName: "star")
            .resizable()
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .scaledToFit()
    }

    var body: some View {
        theImage
            .overlay {
                ZoomableScrollView {
                    theImage
                }
                // Mask out the base image when the
                // zoomable image is shrunk
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It almost works except the image is being cropped

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the image to start at the size of the original image, but if the user zooms it then it should fill more of the display instead of being cropped. In other words, it should expand into the space you were trying to stop it from using in your original post. If the layout of the View is not meant to be affected then I would guess it would best doing this in another layer. How about just using your original solution as a layer in a ```ZStack``` (without the blue background, of course)?